# On PErmises to SQL Azure Reporting solution

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We are planning to replicate the sql server 2008 in permises database to SQL Azure for Reporting purpose.I checked few options and below is my understanding

1. We cannot replicate on premises database to azure using replication
2. We can use DBM and create DB Snapshot every 2 hours [we are okay with 2 hours data behind the primary ]

Anything else you can suggest to get on permises dataase copy to azure for Reporting.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. Use a DAC BACPAC https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156148.aspx
2. Use BCP https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156153.aspx
3. Use Data Sync (Public Preview) recommended not to use for production workloads https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh456371.aspx

For a comprehensive list please look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee730904.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you can configure SQL Replication to a SQL Server in Azure VM. Also DBM or AlwaysOn or any other solution that SQL Server supports.